# Mysql auto increment value issue

Tags: mysql

I have table called order with its one column name 'id' is set auto increment, auto increment id jumped to 9090000 from 6999 with gap of 9090000-6999, just wanted to know how does it happened ?

Comment: have you sometimes before inserted elements and deleted them again without truncating the whole table?

Comment: this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042042/mysql-auto-increment-id-suddenly-jumped-to-maxint-what-could-be-a-reason

Comment: no I have not done any such things, as its my live db..!

Comment: If there are gaps you want to get rid of you can manually reset the auto increment value and then optimize your table.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 1):

If an id is specified as 9090000 when inserted, the auto increment value is adjusted accordingly. This is done to prevent collisions later on when the id may have eventually hit the larger number.

If the larger id is later deleted, the change to the auto increment remains.

---

It is possible to explicitly set it as follows:

```
alter table mytable auto_increment = 9090000
```

Comment: No i have not specified anything directly

Comment: Maybe someone else has, or your application inadvertently did because of a bug. Also see edit to answer for how to explicitly set it.

Comment: This can happen due to bugs in your program most likely, For instance, I had a log table in my database which I used for logging and debugging. Suddenly when I created a new order, which should have had an id of about 5, it had an id of 7965, which was because I used `PDO::lastInsertId()` to get the latest inserted id of the order, but that was changed to that of the log.