# Mysql Strange auto increment increase.

Tags: mysql

Yesterday I found one problem on my project. For some reason for usual insert mysql did increase auto increment from 8 symbols to 10. In binlogs I found this

```
SET INSERT_ID=2147483646/*!*/;
# at 2638426
#140514 18:49:36 server id 31245  end_log_pos 2638810   Query   thread_id=178500933     exec_time=0     error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1400093376/*!*/;
INSERT INTO deals SET NAME = '###', PRICE = 125
```

But it must be around 26513863

```
ID field is: `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Table type: InnoDB

Mysql version: 5.5.31
```

Maybe someone know how can it be, or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A failed insert can still cause the auto-increment column to increase. If your program went into an infinite loop of failures it could cause the limit to be reached.

It's also possible to set the auto-increment programmatically to a specific value.

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable AUTO_INCREMENT = 12345;
```

from "Mark Byers" in this question [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042042/mysql-auto-increment-id-suddenly-jumped-to-maxint-what-could-be-a-reason)

Comment: It was just usual query which didn't change for 2 years already and mysql error log is empty. About alter table, yes I know that it's possible to move AI like that and will do it, but first I need to find a reason.